# Laplace transform using Op-Amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, laplace-transform

Is it possible to design a circuit using op-amps such that it's output gives the Laplace transform of the input signal?Is this idea new?

Here it goes:

Our task is to design a black box. Its property is such that it takes on an input signal and then converts the signal to a signal which would have been obtained if we had operated a Laplace transform. Even though in Laplace transform the result obtained is in 's' domain, we are not interested in converting the signal to frequency domain instead only in the magnitude i.e. if we apply \$sin(wt)\$ we should get \$\dfrac{w}{s^2+w^2}\$ [by Laplace transform] -- changing \$s\$ with \$t\$ --> \$\dfrac{w}{t^2+w^2}\$

Here is [its graph at FooPlot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIxLygxKyh4XjIpKSIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d).

[image]

Comment: The output would be complex (not one-dimensional) so how would you have an output ("it's output") represent a complex thing?

Comment: we are only considering the magnitude of the complex variable 's'..

Comment: An analogue integrator converts "1" to "\$\frac{1}{s}\$" but why don't you give an example of what you might expect - given that some transforms involve N! I don't really think that op-amps can do it but please do offer a simple example of what you might expect as an input and what you'd expect as an output.

Comment: see if the input is 1 then output waveform should be '1/t' a hyperbolic function

Comment: That's an integrator

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Op_amp_integrator --this page at wikipedia is different than what you are saying

Comment: I think you should decide precisely what you are saying to avoid wasting people's time. At the moment, I'm confused by your question because you appear to be rejecting an integrator as something that can convert 1 to 1/s - what are you saying?

Comment: an integrator does not convert 1 to 1/t..it converts 1 to t.

Comment: OK my bad early-morning thinking but you should still give an example that might be useful - call it a black-box with a particular input and state what you want the output to be - magnitude of s doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: our task is to design a blackbox: It's property is such that it takes on an input signal and then converts the signal to a signal which would have been obtained if we had operated a Laplace transform.Even though in laplace transform the result obtained is in 's' domain..We are not interested in converting the signal to frequency domain instead only in the magnitude i.e. if we apply sin(wt) we should get w/(s*s+w*w)[by laplace transform]-->w/(t*t+w*w)

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to avoid having folk to read thru all these comments

Comment: what do you think about the idea?is it possible?

Comment: No I don't think this is possible AND I'm unsure about the graph you linked - why is t*t replaced by 1?

Comment: t*t is replaced by x*x

Comment: I think you need to add units to the axis.

Comment: it's easy sint->1/(1+t*t)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to design a circuit using op-amps such that it's output
>   gives the laplace transform of the input signal?

No, it's not possible.  For example, \$F(0)\$ [is the integral *over all positive time* of the input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition)

$$F(0) = \int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-0t}dt = \int_0^\infty f(t) dt$$

So, you would have to wait 'to the end of time' to get the 'initial' output from your box.

Comment: can't we approximate the integral(breaking the integral to summation)even though it has a large n and device a circuit such as a summing amplifier

Answer (score 2):

This can not be done because the circuit you are trying to design is non-causal.

It has to have nonzero output for all times from negative infinity to positive infinity, even if the input is zero up to some t=0.

If you allow an arbitrary delay between the input and the output then, like Scott says, you are talking about making a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: +1.  If such a box existed, it would have 'knowledge' of the infinite future of the input.

Comment: can you elaborate on how it will have 'knowledge' of infinite future of input?

Comment: @MuditSharma, consider two such boxes - one with input that is the unit step \$u(t)\$ and the other with input \$u(t) - u(t - \tau)\$ where \$\tau > 0\$.  For \$t < \tau\$, the two inputs are identical but the output from the two boxes will be different.  For this to be true, the boxes must 'know' what the input is in the future, i.e., one box knows the input signal remains at 1 for the rest of time and the other box knows that the input signal goes to zero at \$t = \tau\$ and remains there for the rest of time.

Answer (score 1):

No - I don`t think it is possible because I see something like a "domain contradiction" in this task. What you are searching is the following:
An input in the time domain should produce an output signal that is defined in the frequency domain. How could an opamp perform such a task?

Answer (score 1):

Not a true Laplace transform, but you could certainly build an analog spectrum analyzer with op amps, if the magnitude of a snapshot of a signal is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  (Well, can I have multipliers, diodes and switches and not just opamps?)  There use to be things called analog computers.  So if you can write down the mathematical expression you want, I'm pretty sure you could program that into an analog computer.  (But I'm not an expert, perhaps there are limits I'm not aware of.)

For your graph and simple expression.  That looks like a low pass filter, (or integrator as Andy aka said.)  Is the y-axis the output?  And the x-axis is frequency?  (You can't really have negative frequencies.)  If so then a low pass filter and rectifier should give that output.